# $location.path() vs $http.get() - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

What is the difference between `$location.path()` and `$http.get()` in AngularJS ? Both seem to be working the same way in my application (I'm using the calls in a function of my application's controller to respond to a form submission) , but I feel like I'm missing something.

Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: rough answer - `window.location = YOUR_URL` VS.  `var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); req.open("GET", YOUR_URL, true); req.send();` **Redirect** Vs. **Asynchronous Request For Data**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.get()` is generally used for an API call, typically you will retrieve some data with this function.

The `$http` service also has functions for `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc... most HTTP verbs are included to call an external API.

`$location.path()` is mainly used for changing the url of your application, the `$location` service can only issue GET requests and is generally for reading/changing the url of your own, internal application